# Why my table is not insertable?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

Well, I've got two tables: `SaveBatch` and `SaveBatchLocal`. They have equal fields. First table is insertable in Hibernate and second is not. This is my code:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void add(LinkedList<SmsEntity> smsEntityList) {
        try {           
            Session session = null;         
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Iterator<SmsEntity> iterator = smsEntityList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                session.save(iterator.next());                  
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The only thing I change is table name in entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "smsc.SaveBatch")
public class SmsEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nextid")
    private Integer nextId;
    ...
```

If `@Table(name = "smsc.SaveBatch")`

everything is fine, if

`@Table(name = "smsc.SaveBatchLocal")`

no new rows. What is wrong? Also, this is my Oracle SQL Developer pic:

[image]

They have got different icons with unknown meanings.

Comment: Show us hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SaveBatchLocal is a `global temporary` table, which means that its contents are only visible to the connection that inserted them, and are automatically deleted when that session ends.

See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php